# Database Project Management

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-scripts

I wanted to explore ways to develop, manage and architect databases. I would like to do the following things (at least this is what I foresee for now!).

1. Develop schema, specify constraints and capture all the development as installable DB Scripts.
2. Develop stored procedures.
3. Manage the above two with GIT.

What is the norm when it comes to database development?

Are there any drawbacks when it comes to GUI way of doing things (mySQL workbench for example) vs writing individual scripts?

In SQL Workbench how do I capture all the schema information along with stored procedures into 'installable script' so that I can run it later on an actual server and have it recreate (or replicate) the database for me? - I am not too interested in exporting the persistent data.

Comment: I am an old hat, but I really think DBAs must know how to deal with command line. Maybe because when everything crashes, CLI is all you have (when you have). My 2c

Comment: @Leo is 100% correct. All the development should be done via code. No GUI stuff. Altering a table in code is so much easier than doing it via the GUI. Especially when you have to roll that change out to multiple tables.

Comment: @Namphibian I am tending towards that now. I am getting first hand experience on why Workbenches cannot substitute handwritten queries.